# insert facelets template on xhtml page containing google maps api

Tags: jsf

good morning everyone!
I'm having a problem trying to insert a template into a page that uses the Google Maps API.
The Menu.xhtml page is my template and the code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head><title>MONITOR</title></h:head>

<h:body>
    <table><tr><td>
        <h:form id="frmenu">
            <p:menubar>
                <p:submenu label="Vehicles">
                    <p:menuitem ajax="false" value="Taxi" />
                    <p:menuitem ajax="false" value="Bus" />                             
                </p:submenu>
                <p:menuitem ajax="false" value="Exit" />
            </p:menubar>
        </h:form> 
    </td></tr>
    <tr><td><ui:insert name="content"></ui:insert></td></tr>
    </table>                    

</h:body>
```

On the Home.xhtml page I want to insert this template (Menu.xhtml).
I'm following the Facelets documentation, but the map is not plotted.

If anyone can help me, I'll be grateful.

Follow the code of the Home.xhtml page

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:df="http://www.dataci.es.gov.br/ui"
template="Menu.xhtml">

<ui:define name="content">

<style type="text/css">      
#map-canvas { height: 100% }
</style>

<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=#{MyKey}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">    

function initialize() {

    var featureOpts = [{
        stylers: [{ 
            visibility: 'simplified' 
        }]
    }];

    var MY_MAPTYPE_ID = 'custom_style';
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom: 14,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-20.847475, -41.137873),
        type: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        mapTypeId: MY_MAPTYPE_ID         
    });

    var styledMapOptions = {name: 'Custom Style'};

    var customMapType = new google.maps.StyledMapType(featureOpts, styledMapOptions);
    map.mapTypes.set(MY_MAPTYPE_ID, customMapType); 
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);   

</script>

<h:form id="form" preprendId="false">

        <div id="map-canvas">

        </div>


</h:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Comment: I see two pages but no relation between them template wise

Comment: Exact!
Following the Facelets specification, the Home.xhtml page should begin with the ui: composition tag and should remove the head, body.
But if I do this the map is not plotted

Comment: Then show how you tried and let us comment on that

Comment: Hello!
I changed my Home.xhtml page.
But the Google map stopped being plotted
Only displays menu

Comment: I don't see any js for the map. And check the browser-console for errors...

Comment: The funcition initialize() is responsible for starting the map.
I followed the google api documentation,
even this block of code works when I call a xhtml page without templates.
I do not know why when I try to use the templates it does not work.

Comment: The external js that you initially had are not there anymore... please...

Comment: In the browser console I discovered an error in the JS code google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
Gives the following error: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Comment: Read my previous two comments... check your older code... search google (the searchengine)